# Criterion for invertible block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I do have a matrix of following form

$$M:=\left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
A & & * &\\
\hline 0  & &  &\\
0  & & B &\\
0  & &  &\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Here the $0$'s represent matrices of which any entry is equal to $0$. Moreover, $A$ is an invertible square matrix. Is it true, that $M$ is invertible, iff $B$ is invertible? My guess is that in this case, it holds $\det(M)=\det(A)\det(B)$, but I am not completely convinced, if this is true.

Comment: Yes that's true.

Comment: Thank you. Right now, I see that the structure of the $B$ I am looking at is a bit more complicated. In the end $M$ is a square matrix and I have found a solution $x$ for $M\cdot x = b$ with a right-hand side $b$, which in not equal to $0$. (However, some entries of $b$ are equal to $0$.) Is it true, that there is no other $x$, which is a solution?

Comment: Yes, if the matrix is invertible, which is the case since $det(M)\neq 0$, there is exactly one solution of $Ax=b$, which is $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement. $\det M = \det A \det B$ follows from the definition of the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that even if you ignore that in case of $B$ invertible $$\det(M)=\det(A-*B^{-1}0)\det(B)=\det(A)\det(B)$$ it is possible to solve the system easily by blocks:

$MX=0\iff\left(\begin{array}{c|ccc}
A & & C &\\
\hline 0  & &  &\\
0  & & B &\\
0  & &  &\\
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
\hline \\
y\\
\\
\end{array}\right)=0\iff \begin{cases}Ax+Cy=0\\\\By=0\end{cases}$

If $B$ is invertible then $y=0$ so we are left with $Ax=0$ and since $A$ is invertible too then $x=0$ therefore $X=(x,y)^T=(0,0)^T=0$ and $M$ kernel is null therefore $M$ invertible.

If $B$ not invertible there exists $y\neq 0$ such that $By=0$ but since $A$ invertible then we can always calculate $x=-A^{-1}Cy$ making $X=(x,y)^T\neq 0$ an eigenvector of the kernel, thus $M$ not invertible either.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ is not invertible, then its rows are linearly dependent and this is preserved if you pad the rows with the same number of $0$s at the beginning, implying that $M$ is not invertible either.
Now if $B$ is invertible, consider the block matrix $N$ formed by diagonal blocks $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ and everywhere else $0$. Multiplying $MN$ you obtain a block matrix with identities on the diagonal, zeros in the lower left block and something in the top right block. Performing row-echelon reduction on this will land at the identity matrix. Since $N$ is clearly invertible (and with determinant $(det(A)det(B))^{-1}$), I think it follows that $M$ is invertible and that the determinant satisfies the desired equation.